# CSS styling depending on whether a parent flexbox is wrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I want to build a simple webpage, which header looks like this:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#titre {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  display: inline-flex;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
}

#lang {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header">
    <a id="titre" href="...">John Doe</a>
    <nav>
      <a href="...">...</a>
      <a href="...">...</a> ...
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="lang">...</div>
</header>
```

When the `#title` and the `nav` fit on a single row, I want to have this:
[single-line version of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqh2Q.png)

Otherwise, I want all these elements to be displayed row by row:
[multiple-line version of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpmy2.png)

Is possible to do this just with CSS, like conditioning on whether `#header` is wrapped?

Answer (score 0):

#titre{   display: block; } nav a {   display: block; }

Comment: This would only result in the second behavior I want. My question is precisely to know if it is possible to get this behavior *only* when it is not possible to obtain the first (single-line) one.

Comment: no it can't possible

Comment: (Sob!) OK, let's make do with media queries... :'-(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).